# Adding elements of a wchar_t[] string to array<wchar_t>^ without for loop

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am writing a vc++ CLR form project which will control my robot via the serial port. The robot expects an ASCII command as follows: First byte is a character between A and Z which determines the command to execute, the second character is a + or - sign, then there are exactly 5 numbers. If the number to send is less than 5 digits then it is padded with zeros at the start.

I am using System::IO::Ports::SerialPort to communicate with the COM port which has the following prototype:

```
public:
void Write(
    array<wchar_t>^ buffer, 
    int offset, 
    int count
)
```

Since I need to pad the number so it is exactly 5 digits, I am using sprintf. (I am still learning c++ and have not had much experience with String::Format yet, but I assume I can do the same thing there just as easily - but for now I want to do it using these arrays, for the sake of learning).

sprintf returns the string of wchar_t, I now need to add these wchar_t to an < array > to pass to the function however I am having trouble find an elegant solution to this. The solution I have works, however the for loops feel really hacky to me:

```
int DeltaForm::setThetas(int th1, int th2, int th3)
{
// Cannot write more than 5 digits
if (th1 < 1000 && th2 < 1000 && th3 < 1000)
{
    wchar_t commandBuffer[8];
    array<wchar_t>^ buffer = gcnew array<wchar_t>(8);

    _snwprintf_s(commandBuffer, 8, 7, L"B+%05d", th2*100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        buffer->SetValue(commandBuffer[i], i);
    }
    this->serialComms->Write(buffer, 0, 7);

    _snwprintf_s(commandBuffer, 8, 7, L"A+%05d", th1*100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        buffer->SetValue(commandBuffer[i], i);
    }
    this->serialComms->Write(buffer, 0, 7);

    _snwprintf_s(commandBuffer, 8, 7, L"C+%05d", th3*100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        buffer->SetValue(commandBuffer[i], i);
    }
    this->serialComms->Write(buffer, 0, 7);
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
}
```

I have had a look through the array class but could not find any methods which would help me. Is there a simpler, more elegant way to populate an array?

Thanks

Comment: You're mixing a lot of things. C, C++, C++/CLI. They're different and you may find it's faster and easier to pick one of them. If you want to go on with C++/CLI I'd replace all wchar_t arrays with System::String (you can get bytes with Encoder::ASCII->GetBytes and string formatting with String::Format instead of snwprintf). Interop between managed and unmanaged world like this isn't easy to begin with, save your time! Many things are _strange_ in that code (for example why you're using SetValue?). MSDN usually provides .NET counterpart for native functions

Comment: Looks like I have a lot to learn. I don't really know the difference between c++ and c++/CLI :/ I am assuming that c++/CLI is what .NET uses and is managed, whereas just c++ is not? I went with wchar_t because that is what the SerialPort::Write function uses, so I figured I would stick with that to make it a bit simpler. I am using  SetValue because it was the only way I could find to populate the array, in fact my main question was how can I do that more elegantly than with SetValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pin a pointer to the array you can treat it natively, for example:

```
array<wchar_t>^ buffer = gcnew array<wchar_t>(8);
pin_ptr<wchar_t> p = &buffer[0];
_snwprintf_s(p, 8, 7, L"B+%05d", th2*100);
this->serialComms->Write(buffer, 0, 7);
```

I'd also like to elaborate on the point @Adriano made. It seems that you are using Managed C++ throughout your code, and while it was specifically designed to mix C++ with the CLR,it is better to stick to one methodology.

```
System::String^ command = String::Format("B+{0:00000}", th2*100);
array<Byte>^ command_buffer = System::Text::Encoding::Unicode->GetBytes(command);
```

The example uses Unicode because UTF-16 is used by the Windows operating system to represent wchar values, but you should switch that to ASCII if that's what expected on the wire.

Comment: I disagree. Even if it works it doesn't make sense at all. Pin managed array to use sprint instead of string::format?!

Comment: @Adriano I agree with you in general and updated the answer. Notwithstanding C++/CLI is not an island, it is designed to be mixable with C++ and sprintf-ing into an array (even if it is a managed one) isn't that unidiomatic.

Comment: Yes, IMO main reason to use C++/CLI now is that kind of mix but he has no interop here,  just trying to use C (not even C++) function instead .Net counterpart. Anyway now you got my +1!